# Create and use column in create statement same time of table

Tags: sql, db2

I want to create a table with fetch the data from source table.
I can do it using alter and update function but I don't want to do it that way.

I have to create two columns and use 1 column(c1) in other as case statement in second(c2) column.

```
insert into table t
(select 

a,b, case when d>f then 1 else 0 end as c1,
case when c1=1  then "yes" else null end as c2,


from base_temp 
where a>b
)
```

Comment: DB2 <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you might want to look into `SELECT INTO`.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is on how to create a table and populate it with the results of some SELECT statement, then look at the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-table) `as-result-table` syntax.
You may use `AS (full-select) WITH DATA` syntax to create a new table with metadata based on the query provided and insert the result of this query into this table at the same time.

If the question is on how to use column aliases in expressions, then refer to the [Expressions refer to column aliases](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=nps-expressions-refer-column-aliases) topic.
You must have the `SQL_COMPAT` global variable set to the `'NPS'` value in your session to make it work.
You may set it with the `SET SQL_COMPAT = 'NPS'` statement before running the corresponding `SELECT` statement.

```
SET SQL_COMPAT='NPS';

SELECT 
  TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
, CASE WHEN COLCOUNT > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C1
, CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS C2
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you can't or don't want to set this variable, you may use `sub-select` to achieve the same:

```
SELECT
  TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
, C1
, CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS C2
FROM
(
SELECT 
  TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
, CASE WHEN COLCOUNT > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C1
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Comment: in db2 you can directly insert with create symbol ..that is not wrong ..even insert into is not working

Comment: Look at the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=902e4bbdd7ff481c07e03376ae87557e) link. What is "not working" exactly? What's your Db2 platform and version? Edit your question with the exact statement you run and exact error message you get.

Comment: error is column can not be create and insert same time

Comment: Every Db2 error has exact SQLCODE, SQLSTATE and message. Please, don't post your free-form Db2 error interpretations and do the things I asked in by previous comment.